# QML buttons look wrong in PYQT6

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm using PyQt6 and qml to make a application for windows. Now I ran into another problem - qml buttons look wrong when I launch my application through terminal using PyQt6 or PySide6, but if use PySide2 or inside qt design studio these buttons look as it should be.

Here my button code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Button {
    id: testButton
    width: 40
    height: 40

    property url buttonIconSource: "../../Images/Icons/Fullscreen.png"
    property color btnColorDefault: "#000000"
    property color btnColorMouseOver: "#454545"
    property color btnColorClicked: "#2e2e2e"

    QtObject{
        id: internal

        // MOUSE OVER AND CLICK CHANGE COLOR
        property var dynamicColor: if(testButton.down){
                                        testButton.down ? btnColorClicked : btnColorDefault
                                       }
                                   else {
                                        testButton.hovered ? btnColorMouseOver : btnColorDefault
                                       }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        id: buttonBackground
        color: internal.dynamicColor
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image {
            id: iconBtn
            source: buttonIconSource
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            mipmap: true
            smooth: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            visible: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            antialiasing: true
        }
    }
}
```

This is how this button looks in qt design studio or PySide2 - it's correctly highlited now with

```
btnColorMouseOver: "#454545"
```

and mouse pointer not visible in screenshot:

[image]

This is how the same button looks in PySide6 or PyQt6, no different - it's incorrectly highlited with strange blue color (mouse pointer not visible in screenshot)

[image]

Same problem with pressed color

Without mouse hover and not being pressed the button always looks fine

I tried to create new buttons with different properties. Only one thing slightly improved the situation - when I make this button "flat":

```
TestButton {
            id: testButton
            x: 960
            y: 0
            flat: true
```

this helps to see expected color on hover, but when button pressed, all the same I see this strange blue background so this couldn't be a solution.

Please help me undesrtand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to run your example in PySide6 on Ubuntu OK and I got your PySide2 screenshot. I didn't get the strange blue color. However, I decided to post an answer in hopes one of the suggestions within resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- Consider using `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` instead of `width` and `height`
- Consider customizing alternative `Button`-like controls, e.g. `ToolButton`
- Consider using `icon.source` and `icon.color` properties instead of `Image`
- Consider using SVG graphics

I've run this application in PySide6 and it looks similar to your original screenshot:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    ToolButton {
        x: 200
        y: 100
        implicitWidth: 40
        implicitHeight: 40
        icon.source: "FullScreen.svg"
        icon.width: 32
        icon.height: 32
        icon.color: pressed && "grey" || "white"
        background: Rectangle {
            color: parent.pressed && "#2e2e2e"
                || parent.hovered && "#454545"
                || "#000000"
        }
    }
}

// FullScreen.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
<path stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="none" d="
M 1 3 1 1 3 1
M 5 1 7 1 7 3
M 7 5 7 7 5 7
M 3 7 1 7 1 5"/>
</svg>
```

You can also [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACuXicdVLLboMwELz7K1aOlFt5hKBQFHJIpaqXSk1bqWdqXLDi2MiYkKjNv3ch5EEfY3nF7AzrZY3YlNpYWNlVLdiaiAF17rSyRsuKPKU5h08CiPeUrXOja5XF8MyZTVUuUQOmpTYx0FE0jaLbkMKhs79qLZe1tVr177fYxTDxvDPdx+BfUWxCCibsm8hsEcP0t/LARV7YocS0cipdG8axiftayhdmOMfcNqdDV3OsG0yG6aIv+jPff1hpeFXxDMZjoLnhewpfX0CbQlh+qf/PcM56i1O91HBlneuyowlvFx3YW+BJvb3QW25O9mnYrj/tdOR1uIjH6ziQAyGuC8MBkTkG2G2kqhJaWFvGrts0jdMEjja5i3flue0cYSt4s9S7hHrgQQQRXZB5mdoCKvxP1jzp59HTm27SCfUpfAgpE6q0QjFLKHkEHwLcXUQW4tOs2wGyGfLZMSILesWHkLp4YNvK4hs1bLuj)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Only replacing the Button with a ToolButton helped to solve this issue, ToolButton works as expected, even without any changings in my original code. Button causes a blue backlight, whatever I do.